# Azure devOps Pipeline to run all unit tests but exclude others

Tags: unit-testing, filter, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline

**Objective:**
I have a unit test task in my azure devOps pipeline, and I want it to run all tests dll but exclude others.

Run Unit Tests - Run All tests except Tests.XXX.dll and Tests.YYYY.dll

My YAML for the unit test task is :
steps:

```
 task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run All tests except Tests.XXX and Tests.YYYY'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     !**\*test.XXX.dll
     !**\*test.YYY.dll
     **\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    vsTestVersion: 16.0
    runInParallel: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: false
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
```

**Problem**
But what happens is that on the task the Tests.XXX.dll and Tests.YYYY.dll will run and not be filtered.
I think that the (***test*.dll) filter will make the others run (even if they are denied).

**Question**
Does anyone know how to put filters in the test ***test*.dll to eliminate the other projects' tests?
What I am doing wrong?